# In Python, how to get a button the desired size?

Tags: python, button, fonts

how to get the button to a desired size?

Increasing the font size does not work.

```
bou1_1 = Button(fen,text="\u2656",font=("Arial",24), width =9, height =4)  
bou1_1.grid(row =1, column =1)
```

Here is the image of what I get:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I want a square button around this chess symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `width` and `height` parameters:

```
bou1_1 = Button(fen,text="\u2656",font=("Arial",24), width = 18, height = 8)
# 18 and 8 are just examples, set them to whatever you want
bou1_1.grid(row =1, column =1)
```

This will make the entire button larger, not including the text itself. If you want to increase the text size only, then increase the font size.

Comment: Sorry, i tried already but that does not work.  Also, row and column  seems to affect the size too.

Comment: @user2984887 I'm not sure what you meant "doesn't work". Changing the width and height changes the size of the button, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Width does work but not height. It seems that the button expect some text and not a symbol

Comment: To actually show the button as a symbol, you want to use `text = u'\u2656'` --- this interprets the string as a Unicode string, and displays the appropriate character.

Comment: Thanks, it works but I still can't size the button the way I want. Maybe I should use a frame with a mouse over event or something like that.